# Passing Level parameter when transition to next Scene?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

I'm trying to figure out the best way to pass a level parameter between Scenes using Spritebuilder and Cocos2D in Xcode.

I'm using the standard code below to transition between scenes.

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCBReader loadAsScene:@"Gameplay"]];
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the `Gameplay.ccb` has a `GameplayClass` assigned as its custom class, and that class has a property named `currentLevel`, you can access the instance and assign the level as follows:

```
CCScene* theScene = [CCBReader loadAsScene:@"Gameplay"];
GameplayClass* game = (GameplayClass*)theScene.children.firstObject;
game.currentLevel = 3;

[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:theScene];
```

Note that by the time `currentLevel` is assigned the `GameplayClass` will have already run its `init` and `didLoadFromCCB` methods since that happens during `loadAsScene`. If you need further init processing override `onEnter` in `GameplayClass`:

```
-(void) onEnter
{
    [super onEnter]; // must call super

    switch (self.currentLevel)
    {
        // other switches omitted...

        case 3:
            // your level 3 code here
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, I'll try this out when I get home :)

Answer (score 0):

In my game (made with Cocos2d 2.0 + CocosBuilder) I added a class method `loadWithLevelID:levelID` to the class GameObjectLayer that manages the gameplay elements:

```
@implementation GameObjectLayer {
    G1LevelID * _levelID;
}
// load a Luminetic Land game object layer
+ (instancetype)loadWithLevelID:(G1LevelID*)levelID {
    NSString * levelFileName = ... builds levelFileName from levelID;
    GameObjectLayer * gol = (GameObjectLayer*) [CCBReader nodeGraphFromFile:levelFileName];
    [gol setLevelID:levelID];
    return gol;
}
- (void)setLevelID:(G1LevelID*)levelID {
    _levelID = levelID;
}
```

So now I can create a GameObjectLayer typing

```
GameObjectLayer * gol = [GameObjectLayer loadWithLevelID:levelID];
```

In general, adding a "load" method to the classes that map ccbi files offers the following benefits:

1. Only the class knows the name of its related ccbi file.
2. The ccbi file to create a given class is referenced only once in the entire project.
3. All the logic to set up an object (e.g. of type G1GameObjectLayer) is inside the object itself.

I think you can follow a similar approach with your CCScene subclass.